# How to stop a button tap event from bubbling into a listview?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have a listview with a button as part of the datatemplate.  When I click the button I want an action to happen, but I don't necessarily want that item selected.  Is there any way I can stop the tap event from bubbling up to the listbox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure this is the best solution but. Capture the selected index before you get to the method the button activates. Inside of it at the end set selected back to the original.

Comment: Not a bad idea. Not ideal, but I think it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample ListView with a button in it. Clicking on the button does not select the item for me. Can you post your DataTemplate?

But, you can add the following to your click method:

```
myListBox.SelectedItem = null;
```

Where myListBox is the name of your ListBox. This will cause the listbox to have no selected items. If you want to keep the previously selected item, you have to keep the track of previously selected item or index and set the listbox to that item using either:

```
myListBox.SelectedItem = previousItem;
myListBox.SelectedIndex = previousIndex;
```

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned that I don't want to unselect the currently selected item either.